# How do updates work for mobile applications?

Tags: android, ios

My work currently released a mobile app (android and iOS). I know we publish say a new apk when there is a new android build. But do users have to download the entire application every time a new apk is available? Or do users just get the differences and download those instead of the entire application again? Trying to understand how updates actually work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for iOS, but Google Play will attempt to push app differences on updates rather than the whole APK file.  See this article for more info:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html

Comment: So the apk is different than a compiled binary, enabling the file diff and applying only the changes. I was under the assumption it was compiled code.

Comment: APK is really just a zip file that contains the compiled code, resources, assets, etc. When you upload your APK, they unpack it and for each file contained, create a diff that allows them to patch from one app version to another. So while the compiled code is included in this process, there's probably less they can do with it. I'm sure the resources and assets are much easier to diff and that's where the file size savings happens.